# Extra text in WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 POST header

Tags: rest, soap, header, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've been using trying out the WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 to generate REST APIs for a SOAP web service and have successfully traversed the procedures. I enabled message wire tracing in order to view the requests-responses in the logs. I can see that a correctly formatted message is being created and sent to the back end service, however, the response is not as expected.
I've noticed some extra text (usually "**16e**" as in the second to last line) is sent just before the XML payload and is therefore being processed as the payload. I suspect that it's the cause of my problems, but I am unable to trace where it originates.

```
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,792] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "POST /services/services.php HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,792] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Origin: https://api-manager.ug.com:9443[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,792] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "SOAPAction: https://testservices.ug.com/services/services.php/GetAccountBalance_2[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,792] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "activityID: 119801787388364143641044[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,792] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,792] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Referer: https://api-manager.ug.com:9443/[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "testkey: 76d33583-e7f9-42a3-a4ad-d91118f8b043[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "DNT: 1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Content-Type: application/soap+xml[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Host: testservices.ug.com[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,793] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "16e[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-05-12 15:23:55,794] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-5 << "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://testservices.ug.com/soap/TransactionServices"><soapenv:Body><web:GetAccountBalance_2><AccountNumber>001221131211</AccountNumber><AuthToken>111111</AuthToken></web:GetAccountBalance_2></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
```

When I use the XML request and call the back end SOAP service directly, I get a successful response.
Any idea what could be responsible for this text and what I need to do to get rid of it? Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the source of the 16e from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#directives

> **chunked**
>
> Data is sent in a series of chunks. The Content-Length header is omitted in this case and at the
> beginning of each chunk you need to add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format,
> followed by '\r\n' and then the chunk itself, followed by another '\r\n'. The terminating chunk is a
> regular chunk, with the exception that its length is zero. It is followed by the trailer, which consists of
> a (possibly empty) sequence of entity header fields.

The problem turned out to be the content-type. I was sending the value "application/soap+xml" and changed that to "text/xml" by adding the line below in the xml config file for the api found in *<CARBON_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/*

```
<property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

That's all that was required to make it work.